# Bing Search API : how to search for exact domains/websites?

Tags: api, dns, bing

I'm using the Bing API to check the popularity of certain websites.

For example:  `'www.microsoft.com'`  gets millions of results, while `'www.blahblah.com'` gets only a few.

Now there is a problem that Bing appears to not search for exact domains.

For example:   `'www.this-domain.com'`  also gets results for 'www.thisdomain.com' , which is not what I want. Also it finds results that simply have 'this domain' on it!

Even with single or double quotes around the domain, it doesn't seem to matter.

Is there a way to let Bing only search complete and exact domainnames ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `site:www.microsoft.com` to the query, rather than just the domain by itself.